# Thread pool in Java which actually stops() the Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a library call, let's say `Descriptor.compute(Molecule m)`.

This call hangs forever for some molecules (a bug in the library) and for some molecules, it does the computation for a long time. I want to run the computation on server, preferably in multi-threaded or multi-processed way so that all processors can be used. Also, I don't want the computer to spend more time than `TIMEOUT` on any molecule.

Because the `compute` method doesn't do any checking of `isInterrupted()` nor waits anywhere, it doesn't respond to `Thread.interrupt()` call.

So I think I need to use `Thread.stop()` which works fine in stopping this type of task.

My question is: **Is there some Thread pool which is capable of actually stopping the threads?**

I made a simple pool which uses `ArrayBlockingQueue<Input>` and `ArrayBlockingQueue<Result>` for communication. However, I'm getting strange `NullPointerException`s during the `compute()` which I'm unable to trace (these exceptions have also null stack trace). So I'm asking if there already isn't some existing implementation, my googling didn't bring any fruit, everything I've found only `interrupt`s.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: By the way, the library is [CDK](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cdk/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Comment: Hmm.. if you set M to null from another thread, does that force the 'compute' method to throw an exception?  If not, is there some other field within 'Molecule' that is acessed frequently by 'compute' and will force a segfault/AV?

Comment: Each Descriptor implementation behaves differently. There is unfortunately no common safe place to throw an exception.

Comment: "a bug in the library": While that is probably no near-term solution, in the public interest you should file a bug report with them (or vote it up if already present).

Answer (score 2):

There is no good way in Java to "kill" a thread. Read the [long disclaimer on the deprecated Thread#stop method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29). Because of that, no modern API (such as ExecutorServices in the JDK) will make use of this method.

You have to make those threads check for interrupts and termination flags.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Unfortunately, this is not an option for me as the Descriptor interface is implemented by many classes.

Comment: In this case, maybe spawning a new JVM process to do these calculations would work. You can kill processes.

Comment: I already thought about that. Do you know about something as easy as Python's `multiprocessing`? Or what are the tools used usually in Java for high-level IPC?

Comment: That is probably worth another question... The interesting part here being the way to communicate back the results, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you. I will leave the question open in case somebody had another idea.